# Can we get the title by node ID in a template file?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to retrieve the title by node ID, based on the interface language.
I found `drupal_url('/node/101', {absolute: true})`.
I wish to have a similar function that returns a title passing a node ID.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I had to do this in preprocess function

```
function template_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    $variables['node_101'] = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(101)->getTranslation($lang)->getTitle();
    $variables['node_75'] = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(75)->getTranslation($lang)->getTitle();
    $variables['node_103'] = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(103)->getTranslation($lang)->getTitle();
}
```